# Python: Change range location with loop

Tags: python, loops, range

I would like my program to print every other letter in the string "welcome".
like:

```
e
c
m
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
stringVar = "welcome"
countInt = 7

count = 0
oneVar = 1
twoVar = 2

showVar = stringVar[oneVar:twoVar]

for count in range(countInt):
count = count + 1
oneVar = oneVar + count
twoVar = twoVar + count

print(showVar)
```

Though it only shows the 2nd letter "e".
How can I get the variables oneVar and twoVar to update so that the range changes for the duration of the loop?

Answer (score 4):

There is a built in notation for this, called ["slicing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> stringVar = "welcome"
>>> print(stringVar[::2])
wloe
>>> print(stringVar[1::2])
ecm
```

`stringVar` is iterable like a list, so the notation means `[start : end : step]`. Leaving any one of those blank implicitly assumes from `[0 : len(stringVar) : 1]`. For more detail, read the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

Why its not working in your snipet:

Even though you increase oneVar and twoVar inside the loop, there is no change in the showVar as showVar is string which is immutable type, and its printing stringVar[1:2] which is `e` the 2nd index of `welcome`:

**Just to fix your snippet:
You can just try like this;**

```
stringVar = "welcome"
countInt = 7

for count in range(1,countInt,2):
   print count, stringVar[count]
```

Output:

```
e
c
m
```

Comment: He doesn't want every second character :)

Comment: did i put something wrong or ? i think i was explaining why he got only 2nd character.

Comment: He expects only `e
c
m`

Answer (score 0):

Another more complex way of the doing the same would be

```
string_var = "welcome"

for index, character in enumerate(string_var, start=1):  # 'enumerate' provides us with an index for the string and 'start' allows us to modify the starting index.
    if index%2 == 0:
        print character
```